# PHP json_encode of SimpleXMLELement gives different results in different environments

Tags: php, json, xml

I am trying to convert xml to json in php. I tried using json_encode. But the result is different in PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.4 environments. See the below examples.

**Example 1**

```php
$xmlString = '<properties><property name="width">20</property><property name="height">100</property></properties>';
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlString));
```

*Output in PHP 7.4*: @attributes are there for each respective node

```
{"property":[{"@attributes":{"name":"width"},"0":"20"},{"@attributes":{"name":"height"},"0":"100"}]}
```

*Output in PHP 7.2*: @attributes are not there

```
{"property":["20","100"]}
```

**Example 2**

```php
$xmlString = '<property name="width">20</property>';
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlString));
```

*Output in both PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.4 environments*: @attributes are there

```
{"@attributes":{"name":"width"},"0":"20"}
```

**Example 3**

```php
$xmlString = '<properties rank="1"><property name="width">20</property></properties>';
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlString));
```

*Output in PHP 7.4*: @attributes are there for each respective node

```
{"@attributes":{"rank":"1"},"property":{"@attributes":{"name":"width"},"0":"20"}}
```

*Output in PHP 7.2*: @attributes is there only for the parent node

```
{"@attributes":{"rank":"1"},"property":"20"}
```

**Questions**

1. Why the json_encode behaviour is different in the above three examples in different environments?
2. If I always want the output as given in the PHP 7.2 environment (without @attribute properties even in the PHP 7.4 environment), how should I convert the SimpleXMLElement object to JSON format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this change in behavior happened in 7.3.17 / 7.4.5 (see [this example](https://3v4l.org/MU6fq)) and was due to a [bug fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61597). You can confirm this in the SimpleXML section of the changelogs for [7.4.5](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.5) and [7.3.17](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#PHP_7_3).

The easiest way to revert the behavior would probably be to downgrade your PHP version.

It may be possible to use the `$options` parameter of `simplexml_load_string()` to change how it behaves. I'd consult the [manual page](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) and its comments for more information on that.

That option notwithstanding, you may just have to wrap the `simplexml_load_string()` call in another function you write that alters its return value to your preference.

Comment: Looks like the FIX is now doing things correctly, so the suggestion to downgrade does not seem like a viable solution in the long term

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. It seems I have to go for your last solution (wrap the simplexml_load_string() call in another function)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Agreed, sorry, was more intending to put it out there as a possible short-term solution until a better one could be written.